# Using Car Speaker As Music Player in iPhone

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, cydia, audio, speakers

I have an ordinary bluetooth speaker.

I connect to the device using bluetooth and when someone calls me I can hear my ringing tone through the car's stereo and hear the caller's voice through the car's stereo.

Problem is, I can't use this device to play music through the car's stereo. The device only uses the car stereo if someone is calling me.

Is there an app (maybe something from cydia) that can fix that problem? I basically want every sound from my iphone to be played through the car's stereo INSTEAD the iphone's speaker.

Comment: What is the make and model of the car stereo? Unfortunately not all Bluetooth car stereos are equal; they don't all support the part of the Bluetooth protocol that supports streaming audio. (I'm guessing you already know that and you're asking if there's an app to circumvent that issue, but it might still be helpful to know.)

Comment: Yea I already knew that. It's called A2DP by the way and yea I'm looking for an app to fix this limitation.

Answer (score 2):

If your stereo does not register that it supports the A2DP profile, then it likely will also not handle A2DP communication. It is not as simple as finding an app that will "fix the problem", because the problem is likely that your Stereo does not support audio playback. The level of difference between A2DP for audio playback and HSP for maintaining calls is enormous.

Perhaps you may be able to talk to the dealer and see if there is a firmware update for the stereo itself, something they can do to enable this feature. But otherwise, no App can solve it alone.